# How do I ignore a POST request in Flask if a function that I called for the previous request has not finished

Tags: python, flask

I have the following Flask code

```
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/get_bounding_box", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def hello():
    res = call_another_func()

    return "False"



if __name__ == "__main__":
        app.run(debug=True, host='10.0.10.15')
```

The call_another_func() function does some heavy load processing.

In the meantime while call_another_func() is busy processing the previous request, if another request comes through I just want to ignore that request and wait until the function finishes its processing.

How do I implement this in Flask?

Comment: Forgot to ask, are you using any kind of async or multi-worker execution in your project?

Comment: why not use g from from flask import g ans set attribute while a function is running.

Comment: depending on your deployment environment it might be easy to control number of threads for your app, for instance in apache webserver you could configure virtual host for your app to use only 1 thread with line like WSGIDaemonProcess myapp threads=1

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use simple mutex lock and return status on request, not ignore it?

```
app = Flask(__name__)
import threading
call_another_func_lock = threading.Lock()

@app.route("/get_bounding_box", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def hello():
    if call_another_func_lock.acquire(False):
        res = call_another_func()
        call_another_func_lock.release()
        return "False"
    else:
        return "call_another_func is not finished yet"

if __name__ == "__main__":
        app.run(debug=True, host='10.0.10.15')
```

Comment: Let me give this a try now.

Comment: hey, I get this error - TypeError: acquire() takes no keyword arguments

Comment: I just suggested an edit to the answer from a syntax perspective. We just need to write "False" without any keyword

Comment: Now with the latest code I get the following error from Flask:   Traceback 
    response = self.make_response(rv)
    raise ValueError('View function did not return a response')
ValueError: View function did not return a response

Comment: Ok, now it runs smooth but it looks like the lock is never released because for starting the second request it seems to always go into the else block